# Test REST API using Rest Assured Get type returning 400 status code

Tags: java, junit, rest-assured

I'm able to test my REST API through postman client and its giving me the expected response. But, when I try to test through junit, its giving 400 status code

Content type is application/json as per the payload

```java
final static String ROOT_URI = "http://localhost:7000/employees";

@Test
public void simple_get_test() {
    Response response = get(ROOT_URI + "/list?emp=100");
}
```

Am I missing anything

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the port using RestAssured.port = 7000 and remove it from the URI. It would be usefull if you post the response message aside from the code.